# MIDI editor that allows to edit .mid files, keep the many tracks, and have a piano roll to move the notes

Tags: midi, daw

I already used many [DAWs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation) such as Cubase, Ableton Live, Fruity Loops, etc. but I'm looking for the following features:

- can open a MIDI (.mid) file and keep the original structure (if 10 MIDI tracks, keep the different tracks)
- can save into a MIDI file keeping the same structure (if I remember correctly, Ableton's *Export MIDI* feature is limited to one track at a time for example)
- keep all the original MIDI events (not only the NoteOn, NoteOff events, but also the MIDI CC, etc.)
- allows to increase or decrease the speed
- allows to move certain notes with a piano roll like this:

  [image]

**Which MIDI editor allows to do this?**

Comment: Did you already try MidiEditor? https://www.midieditor.org/

Comment: I'm going to try it right now, thanks for the advice @piiperi! This also led me to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MIDI_editors_and_sequencers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This possibilites you will have with the programs Make music Finale of Klemm, Dorico of Steinberg and proably with Sibelius.

https://www.reddit.com/r/composer/comments/9703tw/discussion_dorico_pro_2_vs_finale_when_should_the/

Comment: "Makemusic Finale" is the name of the program (originally just named (Finale). there will  surely be a free trial version:
https://www.klemm-music.de/makemusic/finale/

Comment: Sidenote: The worldwide editor is MakeMusic (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finale_(software) which doesn't cite "Klemm") and the German editor is Klemm indeed ("Im deutschsprachigen Raum wird Finale von Klemm Music Technology vertrieben")

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try these programs!